# OpenCV window must appear in front of all windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, window

I have a GUI dialog box, containing some buttons, which when clicked will call a function to display an image. However, when the button is clicked, OpenCV's window is displayed behind the dialog box. I want the OpenCV window to appear in front of it when the button is clicked.

Here is the snippet of code where window is created and image is displayed.

```
    cv2.namedWindow('image',0)
    cv2.resizeWindow('image',1200,720)

    while(1):
        cv2.imshow('image', self.img_res)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == ord('m'):
            res = 1
            break
        elif k == 27:
            break
```

I have seen some examples with the **win32gui** module, but I'm not sure how to use it here.

(I'm using Python 2.7 in Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your complete code, but when i tried it like this, it stays in front of the window. Hope it helps!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import cv2

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.event = 1
        self.master = master
        self.img_res = img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', 0)
        self.b = Button(self.master, text='Show image', command=self.window)
        self.b.pack()

    def window(self, event=None):
        while self.event == 1:
            cv2.imshow('image', self.img_res)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if k == ord('m'):
                res = 1
                break
            elif k == 27:
                break


def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Addition:

You can also try the import ctypes

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
```